# Bash command to recursively find directories with the newest file older than 3 days

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was wondering if there was a single command which would recursively find the directories in which their newest file in older than 3 days. Other solutions seem to only print the newest file in all subdirectories, I was wondering if there was a way to do it recursively and print all the subdirectories? I tried `find -newermt "aug 27, 2022" -ls` but this only gets me directories that have files younger than the date specified, not the youngest for each directory.

Comment: You are asking two contradictory things.  The "youngest file" is one thing.  "Newest file in older than 3 days" is another.  You want the youngest file regardless of its date or you want the youngest if it is max 3 days old?  FYI please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: My apologies @Nick3500. I meant to refer to the youngest if it is 3 days old.

Answer (score 0):

A long one-liner to sort files by date, get uniq directory names, list by modification keeping first

```
find ~/.config -type f -newermt "aug 29, 2022" -print0 | xargs -r0 ls -l --time-style=+%s | sort -r -k 6 | gawk '{ print $7}' | xargs -I {} dirname {} | sort | uniq | xargs -I {} bash -c "ls -lt --time-style=full-iso {} | head -n2" | grep -v 'total '
```

With comments

```
find ~/.config -type f -newermt "aug 29, 2022" -print0 |\
xargs -r0 ls -l --time-style=+%s | sort -r -k 6 |\ # newer files sorted by reverse date
gawk '{ print $7}' | xargs -I {} dirname {} |\ # get directory names
sort | uniq | \ # get uniq directory names
xargs -I {} bash -c "ls -lt --time-style=full-iso {} | head -n2" |\# list each directory by time, keep first
grep -v 'total '
```

Comment: 0) Why do you sort files by date in the second files? 1) You could replace `xargs -I {} dirname {}` with `xargs -n1 dirname`. 2) You could replace `sort | uniq` with `sort -u`.

Comment: @LMC thank you. I thought the approach would be to use ` -exec ` to execute a different find within the original.

Comment: @Bengi34 may be there's a way to use `-exec` but at expenses of a complex syntax.

Comment: @NO_NAME 0) to get the first by time in that directory. 1) you would missed many directories if keeping the first only. 2) Yeah, that would work

Comment: @LMC 0) I still don't see how the order is relevant for anything that happens after that line. 1) No, it would still process them all. Earlier, I though both ways produce exactly equivalent results. Now, I've read `-I` also makes it threat only new lines as input separators instead of all white spaces, so your way seems to be better, although, `-n` is more portable. (I usually do `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0n1 <command>` for portability.)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the requirements correctly, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

find dir -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d "" d; do               # traverse "dir" recursively for subdirectories assigning "$d" to each directory name
    if [[ -n $(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f) \
        && -z $(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -3) ]]; then       # if "$d" contains file(s) and does not contain files newer than 3 days
        echo "$d"                                                       # then print the directory name "$d"
    fi
done
```

A one liner version:

```
find dir -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d "" d; do if [[ -n $(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f) && -z $(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -3) ]]; then echo "$d"; fi; done
```

Please modify the top directory name `dir` according to your file location.